# How to get size of hdfs directory using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Don`t know exactly how to start but , in my use case I am trying to get the size of my HDFS dir using Scala, can someone help here?

I am about to reach this step, but dont know what should I do from here?

```
val fi = hdfs.listStatus(new Path("/path/path")
fi.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath))
```

Answer (score 3):

For the pyspark version and Hadoop cluster deployed on Kubernetes (address is handled via DNS) you can do the following

```
hadoop = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop

fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
conf.set( "fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hdfs.hdfs:/myhomefolder" )
path = hadoop.fs.Path('/path/')

print(fs.get(conf).getContentSummary(path).getLength())
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you size (disk space) in bytes of HDFS directory using scala spark

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

fs.getContentSummary(new Path("/path/path")).getLength
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a `FileStatus` instance.

```
val fi = hdfs.listStatus(new Path("/path/path")
```

You can call the `getBlockSize` on `FileStatus`.

Following is the documented method in the class

```
/**
   * Get the block size of the file.
   * @return the number of bytes
   */
  public long getBlockSize() {
    return blocksize;
  }
```